# JAVA Code to print SQL Server to CSV returns with incomplete data

Tags: java

I have a JAVA code to out put SQL Server Table to CSV. The printing is stopping in the middle and I am getting only partial data as CSV output. Below my code.

```
public class SQLServerConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection conn = null;
        SQLConnection cnn = new SQLConnection();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(cnn.fileName);

        try {conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cnn.dbURL);

        if (conn != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
        }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 

        String sql = String.format(cnn.Query);
        assert conn != null;

        PreparedStatement preStatement;
        preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rmsd = result.getMetaData();
        int Columncount = rmsd.getColumnCount();

      //Get the column name and print the column name
        for (int iterator=1; iterator<= Columncount; iterator++) {
            fw.append(rmsd.getColumnName(iterator)+",");
        }
        fw.append('\n'); 

        while(result.next()){
            try {
                for (int jterator=1; jterator<=Columncount; jterator++){
                    fw.append(result.getString(jterator));
                    fw.append(',');
                }
                fw.append('\n');
             } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        conn.close();
    }}
```

Class for DB and Excel Parameters

```
public class SQLConnection {
    public String ServerName = "Server1";
    public String DBName = "DB1";
    public String FileLoc = "Location of the file";
    public String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+ServerName+";databaseName="+DBName+";integratedSecurity=true";
    public String Query = "SELECT * from [scdHSBCHK]";
    public String fileName = (FileLoc + DBName +"_QueryResult.csv"); 
}
```

The actual db returns 57 records but the csv returns only 29. I tried with different db names as well same issue though. When I output the results in the program window, the data is displaying correctly.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Yes. Did a debug and found that the issue is with the file writer as the data coming correct when I did a print within eclipse. After that I couldn't progress on anything.

Comment: Google for "try-with-resources", learn what it's about, and use it for all the resources that **must** be closed: Connection, PreparedStatement, and of course, FileWriter. Also, use a BufferedWriter as explained in the Java IO tutorial. Writing with a FileWriter like this is slooow.

Comment: How many Columns from first loop do you have?

Comment: Note that Windows users would expect a CSV file to have `"\r\n"` line endings. To make it platform-independent, you should use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `'\n'` or use `BufferedWriter.newLine()`.

Comment: @AlexGera I have 22 columns from the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure that you close the `FileWriter`. This will ensure that all buffers are flushed to the file. Make sure that all `Closeable` resources are closed (Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, FileWriter), by using try with resources.

My suggested implementation would be something like:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLServerConnection {

    private static final String LINE_SEP = System.lineSeparator();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SQLConnection cnn = new SQLConnection();
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(cnn.dbURL, cnn.user, cnn.pass);
             PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(cnn.Query);
             ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
             Writer fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cnn.fileName))) {
            ResultSetMetaData rmsd = result.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rmsd.getColumnCount();
            //Get the column name and print the column name
            for (int iterator = 1; iterator <= columnCount; iterator++) {
                fw.append(rmsd.getColumnName(iterator)).append(",");
            }
            fw.append(LINE_SEP);
            while (result.next()) {
                try {
                    for (int jterator = 1; jterator <= columnCount; jterator++) {
                        fw.append(result.getString(jterator)).append(',');
                    }
                    fw.append(LINE_SEP);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Closing the FileWriter also implicitly flushes it. Also the Class.forName call is unnecessary. It was only needed in versions of JDBC drivers that were written 10-20 years ago.

Comment: Excellent, I am getting the correct data after closing the File Writer. Thanks @DodgyCodeException